# Remove \n from the start of the string c#

Tags: c#, string, newline

I have a string which look like "\n\n\n\ABC\n XYZ", i just want to remove all my new line character from starting of the string.

```
string replacement = Regex.Replace(s, @"\n", "");
```

If i use this one so it will remove all new line from string which i don't want.

Comment: `string.TrimStart()` or `string.Trim()`

Comment: @MartinParkin's `TrimStart` solution is the way to go.  However, if you are wedded to Regex, consider something like: `^(\\n)+`.  The `^` says "only consider stuff at the beginning of the line".  The `+` says "one or more`.  So together, you get "get all the new-lines (one or more) at the beginning of the line"

Answer (score 13):

If you are just looking to remove newline characters from the start of a string, why not use `TrimStart`:

```
string s = "\n\n\n\nABC\n XYZ";
string replacement = s.TrimStart('\n');
Console.WriteLine(replacement);
```

This will remove all the leading `\n` characters from the string. Output:

```
ABC
 XYZ
```